# finding specific series of dates between two dates

Tags: excel-2013

Im trying to do formula that finds a series of dates from A3 to A6 which falls between two dates H4 and I4 then when find any date sum (holidays) in J4

screenshot of work

[image: My File]

Answer (score 0):

I tried this formula after long time and here is the answer

=SUMIFS(Holidays[Days],Holidays[Holi Start],">="&H4,Holidays[Holi Start],"<="&I4)

if any one have better answer please provide it :)